# Flask-WTF - Create a field that must be unique and can't be left blank

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

in model.py

```
github = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=True)

emergency_number = db.Column(db.String(12),unique=True,nullable=True)
```

in form.py

```
github = StringField('Github')

emergency_number = StringField('Emergency Number',validators=[Length(min=10,max=12)])
```

I want to create a database such that , a user may not enter this form and leave it blank, but if user enter the content should be unique

but problem is while filling form if 1st user leave it blank no other user are able to leave it blank

*This github account is takem.Please choose a different one*

*Field must be between 10 and 12 characters long.*

error for these form

Answer (score 0):

A `custom validator` will do.

```
class FooForm(FlaskForm):
    emergency_number = StringField('Emergency Number',validators=[Length(min=10,max=12)])
    def validate_emergency_number(form, field):
        if not field.raw_data:
            number = Foo.query.filter_by(emergency_number=form.field.data).first()
            if number:
                raise ValidationError('Emergency number must be unique')
        raise ValidationError('Emergency number cannot be blank')
```

You can also create a new Validator.

```
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError

class Unique(object):
    def __init__(self, model, field, message='Emergency number should be unique'):
        self.model = model
        self.field = field

    def __call__(self, form, field):
        if not field.raw_data:
            check = self.model.query.filter(self.field == field.data).first()
            if check:
                raise ValidationError(self.message)
        raise ValidationError(message='Emergency number cannot be blank')

emergency_number = StringField('Emergency Number',validators=[Length(min=10,max=12), Unique(Foo, Foo.emergency_number)])
```